# NSTableViews in NSOutLineViews

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I have a requirement to fill the outline view with table views as shown in the image. There will be only one child table view for each nsoutlineview node. The number of table views is not static.  So, I will need to implement the NSOutlineView programmatically.

![Outline view named "Command" as shown in the the image][1]
[image]

Can somebody please suggest on, how to go ahead with the requirement?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The above is NOT an outline view with table views as children. It's achieved with an NSOutlineView using a root node for "Xcode Menu" and "File Menu" as root nodes and all the children as leaves. Turn on header rows (it's a header row if it's a root node) and that's that.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I missed that. It was just an example. But would it be possible to have a table view as a child to outline view node?

Comment: It'd be possible but a lot more work. Why is it you still feel you need to do this?

Comment: If you think, it's quite a deal of work, then I would go with the above Outline view style. How to turn on header rows for root nodes?

Comment: For this, you'll need to dig into the documentation. It's all pretty clearly laid out. If you get stuck, post a separate, specific question.